# regex to catch commented lines of a conf file

Tags: regex, bash, sed

In order to find this line `pm.max_children = 50` inside a conf file and change it to `pm.max_children = 5`, I am using this:

`s/^\(pm.max_children = \).*/\15/`

In the case, the line may or not be commented (with ';' or '#'). How can I deal with that in a single regex to work with sed?

If the CONF_FILE has this content:

```
pm.max_children = 500
;pm.max_children = 500
#pm.max_children = 500
```

This is what I need to accomplish:

```
pm.max_children = 5
pm.max_children = 5
pm.max_children = 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed on my machine doesn't seem to support `?`, but you can use `*` instead:

```
s/^[#;]*[:space:]*\(pm.max_children = \).*/\15/
```

This matches 0 or more `#` or `;` characters followed by 0 or more whitespace characters.

If you don't care what precedes your keyword, use this, which is simpler, but matches anything:

```
s/^.*\(pm.max_children = \).*/\15/
```

Comment: Thanks, Noa. The only things that will come before the keyword is '#', ';' or nothing at all. There would be no space. So I could do this: `s/^[#;]*\(pm.max_children = \).*/\15/g` and close the deal.